# ImportError: No module named transport (Paramiko, Python 3.2.5)

Tags: python-3.x, importerror, paramiko

I installed PyCrypto and Paramiko (in their respective directories) with

```
python3 setup.py install
```

and both were installed successfully. However, when I try

```
import paramiko
```

in the 3.2.5 interpreter, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.2/lib/python3.2/site-packages/paramiko/__init__.py", line 64, in <module>
     from transport import SecurityOptions, Transport
ImportError: No module named transport
```

I have no idea why it's doing this, as I checked in the folder and the `transport.py` module is there. Why is there then an `ImportError`?

Comment: Hersh : how did you fix the problem? I'm getting the same error with paramiko 1.7.5 python 3.3....

Comment: I think the below answer deserves to be accepted.

Answer (score 2):

It appears Paramiko is trying a relative import, which is not recognised in this form in Python 3 anymore. See [the changes in Python 3](http://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.0.html#removed-syntax).
The import statements in Paramiko should be one of

```
from .transport import SecurityOptions, Transport
```

(note the leading dot), or

```
from paramiko.transport import SecurityOptions, Transport
```

You can either fix the paramiko source code, or as a workaround, you could add `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.2/lib/python3.2/site-packages/paramiko` to your `PYTHONPATH`. Neither are preferred.

Did you run the `2to3` tool before you ran `python3 setup.py install`? I'm not sure if that would fix this though, since the tool probably can't distinguish between a relative or absolute import in the way it is used here.

Do check on the Paramiko forums (if there are) and file a bug against Paramiko for Python 3 compatibility.

**Edit**

It appears you already did [file a bug report](https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko/issues/198).