# Paramiko: ImportError: No module named 'transport'

Tags: python, python-3.x, paramiko

I installed paramiko 1-7-5 using:

```
wget http://www.lag.net/paramiko/download/paramiko-1.7.5.zip
unzip paramiko-1.7.5.zip
cd paramiko-1.7.5
python setup.py install
```

on using import paramiko in python scrips am getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "psql.py", line 8, in <module>
import paramiko
File "/home/nish/.pythonbrew/pythons/Python-3.3.0/lib/python3.3/site-packages/paramiko-1.7.5-py3.3.egg/paramiko/__init__.py", line 69, in <module>
from transport import randpool, SecurityOptions, Transport
ImportError: No module named 'transport'
```

I tried to find similar posts but could not find an answer. How can I fix this error.

FOLLOWING IS THE PYTHON SCRIPT I'M USING:

```
#! /usr/bin/python

import shlex
import os
import subprocess
import string
import random
import paramiko


cmd = 'ssh -i FILE.pem root@EC2instance
args = shlex.split(cmd)
print("\n")
print (args)
p=subprocess.Popen(args)
p.wait()


cmd = 'psql'
print("\n")
print(cmd)
p=subprocess.Popen(cmd)
p.wait()
```

following is the error I'm getting on changing

```
from transport import randpool, SecurityOptions, Transport
```

to

```
from paramiko.transport import randpool, SecurityOptions, Transport
```

or

```
from paramiko.transport import SecurityOptions, Transport

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "psql.py", line 8, in <module>
import paramiko
File "/home/nish/.pythonbrew/pythons/Python-3.3.0/lib/python3.3/site-packages/paramiko-1.7.5-py3.3.egg/paramiko/__init__.py", line 69, in <module>
from paramiko.transport import SecurityOptions, Transport
File "/home/nish/.pythonbrew/pythons/Python-3.3.0/lib/python3.3/site-packages/paramiko-1.7.5-py3.3.egg/paramiko/transport.py", line 364
out = '<paramiko.Transport at %s' % hex(long(id(self)) & 0xffffffffL)
                                                                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: can you simply `import paramiko`?

Comment: So, what's the traceback of that?

Comment: @Ben I wrote a scrip with a single line "import paramiko". and I'm getting the same error "ImportError: No module named 'transport'"

Comment: So, does the file `transport.py` exist in that folder? If it doesn't it's probably worth just reinstalling Paramiko...

Comment: @Ben : transport.py is there in paramiko folder

Comment: Are you on python 3? Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18179156/importerror-no-module-named-transport-paramiko-python-3-2-5